# Angular Facebook service hits API call limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to call my Facebook service within a ng-repeat but somehow the Facebook API call limit is hit very quickly.

I have a service as so:

```
angular.module('core').factory('Facebook', ['$q',
    function ($q) {
        return {
            getMutualFriends: function (fbUserId) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var path = "/" + fbUserId;

                FB.api(
                    path,
                    {
                        'fields': 'context.fields(mutual_friends)'
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                            deferred.reject('Error occured');
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }
                    }
                );
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

And within my controller, I have a function that calls the service:

```
$scope.getMutualFriendsCount = function (fbUserId) {
    if (fbUserId === '' || fbUserId === undefined) return 0;

    Facebook.getMutualFriends(fbUserId)
        .then(function (response) {
            // untested response
            return response.context['mutual_friends']['summary']['total_count'];
        });
}
```

In my template, I have `data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles"` and for each profile, I try to bind the results `data-ng-bind=getMutualFriends(profile.fbId)`.

The service manages to communicate with the FB servers until I start noticing that there are way too many calls during the loop and the call limit is hit very quickly (within 1 or 2 refreshes on my dev machine on page of 20 profiles only). Does anyone have any idea on how I could better design the approach to obtain mutual friends for multiple ids?

Comment: Where do the user ids come from – are they the friends of the current user (read via API), or are they from a different source? If you have a list of ids, you can use `?ids=id1,id2,id3,…&fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)` (for up to 50 ids in one go)

Comment: The IDs are from users who have logged into the app via Facebook. We are trying to determine if the current request user has mutual friends with the profiles that were loaded. Passing multiple IDs may work, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call a function that makes an HTTP request from a watched expression, whether it's `ng-bind` or the equivalent `{{ }}`. This expression, and the subsequent HTTP call` will get called on **every** digest cycle - clearly not what you expect or need.

Instead, get the data that you need and store it, for example, with each `profile`, and access that value from within the `ng-repeat`.

Also, as per the comment above, you should consider calling Facebook in a batch. Create a separate service to handle all of this complexity and expose a simple API to the controller.